# js: unable to pass parameter to anonymous function in setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, settimeout, anonymous-function

I seem to be unable to pass parameter to an anonymous function as the argument of a setTimeOut call. Here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/5xg5d6pp/

```
var arr = ["Just a test","I miss you so much darling #$%&%@;..\]]/"];

console.log(arr);
for(var c=0; c < arr.length; c++){
    console.log(arr[c]);

    //wait 1 sec for next loop
    setTimeout(function(arr[c]) {
        do_magic(arr[c]);
    }, 1000);
}

function do_magic (passed_var){
    console.log(passed_var);
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ `....

Comment: Yes, because I added the parameter in the anonymous function...If I remove it, the code works, but then I dont get arr[c] values at all inside the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Lol the solution there seems a bit convoluted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this `setTimeout(function(arr[c]) {`
You are defining a new function and saying that I want this function to accept a parameter called 'arr[c]', you aren't saying that you want to pass arr[c] to it and because you can't have any special characters in the name of a parameter you get an error. What you should do is define a function outside of the loop to avoid the loop closure issue and pass the parameter to that letting that function create the setTimeout for you. Please see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for more information about closures. Also read this to learn more about javascript functions: http://javascript.info/tutorial/functions-declarations-and-expressions

This is the correct code below:

```
var arr = ["Just a test","I miss you so much darling #$%&%@;..\]]/"];

console.log(arr);
for(var c=0; c < arr.length; c++){
    console.log(arr[c]);

    setTimeoutFactory(arr[c]);
}

function do_magic (passed_var){
    console.log(passed_var);
}

function setTimeoutFactory(text) {
setTimeout(function() {
        do_magic(text);
    }, 1000);
}
```